# SQL MS Access - Invalid Use of Null

Tags: sql, ms-access, debugging

I have now got rid of the overflow on this query by forcing to a long but now I get

**Error 94: Invalid Use of NULL**

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be?

SQL Query:

```
Sum(CLng(
  [TotaalPrijs]/([tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal]*[Totaal])*
  [tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal]
)) AS GezaagdeOmzet
```

Answer (score 4):

One or more of the column values is `NULL`, and this can not be converted to an integer so is causing this error. Try wrapping the value in the `Nz` function e.g. `Nz([My_value],0)`

This will force it to return `0` if a `NULL` is found.

Answer (score 3):

One of your Columns has the value `NULL`. Then the result from your calculation would be `NULL` and you tried to convert to an `Integer` which would yield the error you are seeing.

Try this adjustment to your SQL Query:

```
Sum(CLng(
   Nz(
      [TotaalPrijs]/([tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal]*[Totaal])*
         [tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal],
      0
   )
)) AS GezaagdeOmzet
```

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say for sure without more information, but is `TotaalPrijs`  or `Aantal`  NULL in your data?