# Why am I getting an "Invalid use of Nulls" error in my query?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I use a userform in Excel to run some internal queries between my spreadsheets.
However I am getting `Invalid Use of Null`. I am aware of the `nz` null syntax ([SQL MS Access - Invalid Use of Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042573/sql-ms-access-invalid-use-of-null)), however my queries can be quite large, and I am wondering if there is anything I can add to my VBA code to allow nulls.

Comment: What about `ISNull()` function?

Comment: We'd need to see the SQL being executed against the database.  I'd guess one of your parameters being passed in isn't handling null correctly so something like `where SomeField = NULL` is occuring when you need it to be `where somefield = nz(Parm,'')`  But as it stands not enough info to really help.

Comment: I see two options; in each selected value in the outer most select wrap the field name in NZ(fieldName,'') to ensure all nulls are handled there: 2) wrap each selected value in the inner queries in the NZ(FieldName,'') to ensure nulls are handled there.  The problem will occur anytime you have a NULL value being compared via string comparisons such as IN, = <>,  Now in the subqueries where you're ensuring the value is not null; you're fine on; it's one of the values you're not ensuring is not null;  which would take some time to figure out

Comment: Might start with adding NZ here... `select [poly_EUC_ID],nz(RiskReportProductType,''),PolyMaturity from [mapped_polytypes$]`  then the fields involved in each switch statement if not handling the null's in inline view/derived tables.  when using NZ in a query you'll need to re-alias the column to the same name again however...

Comment: @xQbert , I tried for this one line, not sure if I got to add this to them all, but i am now getting error `Undefined function 'nz' in expression`

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php shows NZ being used as a function in a SQL statement to return the first non-null value `NZ(FieldName,'')`  Where did you try it in the RiskReportPRoductType line? and alias the column `RiskReportProductType`?

Comment: Sorry , I only did it on the Select Poly EUC ID line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Casting functions, like `CStr`, are very prone to trigger *Invalid use of null*. There shouldn't be a need to use `CStr` in joins, as it will typecast to get equality.

Remove the `CStr` on the following locations:

```
on cstr(map_transit.[Transit])=cstr(master.[Transit # (not rollup)])
```

and

```
on cstr(map_rfcurve.[Currency])=cstr(map_curr.[EnterpriseCurrency]))
```

Note that, while you've filtered with `Is Not Null` in those subqueries, the optimizer might first do the join, then throw an `Invalid Use Of Null`, before filtering. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804658/7296893) for a sample case where the optimizer did something similar.

Alternately, if you really want to cast to a string, you can use the following:

```
on (map_transit.[Transit] & '' = master.[Transit # (not rollup)] & '')
```

Appending an empty string to something casts its value to a string, even if it's Null, without throwing an error.